# image size to avoiding of going to blurry in android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

i have some problems with images and icon's in my android development. some times my images and icon's goes blurry and does not crisp and sharp. now i want to do this:
i create a 960px x 720px image layout in Photoshop and create my interface in it. for example buttons etc. and put that image(UI elements in the hdpi folder) in this way i see them in my nexus 4 in nice condition but its not perfect crisp and sharp images. and then for some images that goes to bad quality in small phones due to scaling down, i want to create a smaller size of images and put them into the ldpi folder. is this a right direction? how can i calculate right dimensions for 4 main screen sizes? i s this a good choice of creating my main layout in a 960px x 720px layout size? for example when i create my layouts and icons in  480px x 761px all of images and icones goes to blurry  in my nexus 4! please help me to pass this obstacle.

Comment: uhm... capitalisation and general readability would be very nice, sorry I would edit myself but this looks like a lot of work :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your images or backgrounds using the nine-patch technique, ir order to scale correctly to any device screen resolution.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

If you have icons or images that cannot be scale in this way (like pictures), then you should render it in different resolutions and save them in different drawable folders, as described in this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: you know, for example i have to use a digital painting image in my app. its bigger than of an icon but it goes blurry. in some apps i see that there is a one copy of image in source but it shows nicely in all screen sizes

Comment: If you have a digital image bigger than the real display size, i.e, a thumbnail icon, you can scale down the image without looking blurry. However you must keep the aspect ratio or crop the image to fit into the smaller imageview. Anyway your question is not clear, you can add some device captures for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Images should be made 4 times.

1. ldpi: 75%
2. mdpi: 100%
3. hdpi: 150%
4. xhdpi: 200%

When you make an app for Tablets and Phones you can add folders with screen size selectors using ie: sw600

Layouts work with DP. 1DP is 1PX in mdpi and scales accordingly. Using the MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT values for sizes makes the layout scaleable.

Comment: Tom Dezentje: you says that, for example the resolution for normal devices is 470dp x 320dp and then if i want to create it for hdpi size, i have to scale up this numbers to 150% and turn it for example to the 705 x 480 (150% of 470dp x 320dp) ? it is true?

Comment: There is no static screen resolution. You develop a layout with scaleable parts. Every layout should be able to scale both horizontal and vertical.

Answer (score 0):

make the image 600px wide and resize in manually to 300px to make it crisp.

Just make the pic large and scale it down in whatever program you are using